# Remove many relationships in firebase cloud firestore

Tags: firebase, cloud, google-cloud-firestore

I execute the following batch:

```
batch.set(doc, {
   "Users": {
      [userKey]: null
   }
}, { merge: true })
```

It places the null value for the relationship but does not delete it.

I need to delete the field and value of the object as it does in realtime database and not to be kept with a null value.

If I use firebase.firestore.FieldValue.delete() only works with the object and not with its fields.

Comment: Did you try batch.doc(docid).collection('Users').doc('userKey').delete()?

Comment: batch.doc(docid).collection('Users').doc('userKey').delete()‌​ would delete `userKey` document with a `Users` subcollection, but doesn't delete fields within a document `FieldValue.delete()` is the way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

For better or worse, Firestore treats the `null` value as distinct from a field not existing, so setting a value to `null` won't do what you want.

`FieldValue.delete()` the way to delete fields, not documents, so this *should* delete the field:

```
batch.set(doc, {
  "Users": {
    [userKey]: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.delete()
  }
}, { merge: true });
```

However there's currently a bug in the released SDK that prevents this from working as intended. For now use

```
batch.update(
    'Users.userKey',
    firebase.firestore.FieldValue.delete());
```

Comment: I tried this: "[userKey]: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.delete()" but failed indicating that it only worked with the root field.

Comment: Then try this: "'Users.userKey',firebase.firestore.FieldValue.delete()" but I did not know how to set "userKey" as a dynamic value.

Comment: If you have the userKey you want to delete in a variable called userKey, you can just concatenate: 'Users.' + userKey. Field paths are just strings.

Comment: This test had also done it and it does not work. When concatenated ('Users.' + UserKey) does not take the userKey string, then concatenate it in this way ('Users.' + [UserKey]) and give error

Comment: What I ended up doing was what Kato suggested, I include Users as a collection and not as an object. The problem with that is that when I want to get the relationships I have to do another query to firebase.